# Cartesian product from list of Strings

Tags: string, list, delimiter

To answer this question you need to write code that will produce
a list of strings that contains all combinations that can be made
from two input lists by taking an element from the first list and
following it by an element of the second list (with a space in between).

The ordering of elements in the new list should be determined
primarily the the ordering in the first list and secondarily 
(for elements with the same same first part) by the ordering
of the second list.
So, if the first input is of the form:  A, B, .. X
        and the second is of the form:  1, 2, .. n
the output would be of the form:
  ["A 1", "A 2", .. "An", "B 1", "B 2", .. "Bn", .. "X 1", "X 2", .. "Xn"]

(where the ".." indicates there can be more elements in between).

NOTES: 
1. There can be different numbers of elements in the two lists.
2. If the first list has M elements and the second list has N elements,
   then the output list should have M*N elements.

""" )

```
print("INPUT:")
listA=[] #Creating a list
listB=[]#Creating a second list
listC=[]


while True:
        print("add element y to continue")
        if input()!='y':
            break
        else:
            print("keep adding or x to break" )
            while True:
                if input=='x':
                    break
                else:
                    input_listA = input( "Enter first comma separated list of strings: " )

                    print(n)
                    listA.append(input_listA)
                    print(input_listA)
                    print(listA)
                if input=='x':
                    break
                else:
                    input_listB=input( "Enter second comma separated list of int: " )
                    input_listB.split()
                    listB.append(input_listB)
                    break
```

> however when i right words it for instance ["black ham ", "twice mouse", "floating cheese", "blue elf", "electric elf", "floating elf"] in the calculation for the cartesian product will be calculatin characters not words like 'b', 'l','a','c','k' how can i make the strings words inside the list and also how can i print it in the form of i mean without commas because as you can see i input delimiter along the strings

Comment: You ask for comma separated words, but you never split the string you get on commas.

Comment: Also please post the code you were actually trying. The code above does not even run (e.g. it contains `print(n)` where `n` is not defined)

Comment: import itertools
import re
import shlex
import string                          import them to run

Comment: erase --> print(n)

Comment: does it run ? it should run

Comment: how do i split it i tried to many things and nothing work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import itertools

a = input("Enter first comma separated list of strings: ")
b = input("Enter second comma separated list of strings: ")
result = []
for i in itertools.product(a.split(","), b.split(",")):
  result.append("".join(map(str, i)))

print(result)
```

Result:

```
~ $ python3 test.py
Enter first comma separated list of strings: aa,bb
Enter second comma separated list of strings: 1,2,3
['aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3', 'bb1', 'bb2', 'bb3']
```

---

If you'd rather like a space between the two words in each pair, change

```
result.append("".join(map(str, i)))
```

to

```
result.append(" ".join(map(str, i)))
```

Output:

```
['aa 1', 'aa 2', 'aa 3', 'bb 1', 'bb 2', 'bb 3']
```

Comment: AWESOME SOLUTION THANK YOU!!