# Cartesian product of list of strings using recursion

Tags: python, cartesian-product

Given an input n and strings, for example:

```
3
abc
de
fgh
```

How can I produce this output, using recursion?

```
adf
adg
adh
aef
aeg
aeh
bdf
bdg
bdh
bef
beg
beh
cdf
cdg
cdh
cef
ceg
ceh
```

Comment: You want to identify the logic and patterns first. Notice how the n-th letter is always one of the n-th string.

Comment: Another one with list of strings [cartesian product from list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900628/cartesian-product-from-list-of-strings)

Comment: Did you solve it without recursion? Do you need help with understanding recursion or permutations?

Comment: i didnt solve it i dont know how to in the first place, what is required of us is to sovle that reccursively which i dont know how to do so

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a regular `itertools.product`;

```
In [20]: list(itertools.product('abc', 'de', 'fgh'))                            
Out[20]: 
[('a', 'd', 'f'),
 ('a', 'd', 'g'),
 ('a', 'd', 'h'),
 ('a', 'e', 'f'),
 ('a', 'e', 'g'),
 ('a', 'e', 'h'),
 ('b', 'd', 'f'),
 ('b', 'd', 'g'),
 ('b', 'd', 'h'),
 ('b', 'e', 'f'),
 ('b', 'e', 'g'),
 ('b', 'e', 'h'),
 ('c', 'd', 'f'),
 ('c', 'd', 'g'),
 ('c', 'd', 'h'),
 ('c', 'e', 'f'),
 ('c', 'e', 'g'),
 ('c', 'e', 'h')]
```

Comment: this wwould work but we're not allowed to solve it using that, we have to solve it using recurssion